# How do I remove a UIViewController from the view while adding a different one?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

On one view controller lets say `UIViewController1`, I have a UIButton instance that when clicked I want it to remove the current controller (self) from the stack and add on a different one, we will call it `UIViewController2`.

```
-(IBAction) pressedButton: (id) sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    AppDelegate.rootViewController = [[UIViewController2 alloc] init];
}
```

I know this way doesn't work, but what is a good way to implement this? Or am I looking at the whole concept incorrectly?

Comment: have you tried with viewcontroller dissmissviewcontroller animated:YES on completion -> present view controller animated:NO on the completion block?

Comment: That works! Didn't know this method existed. But I think I am writing the code inefficiently. I don't think I should be adding view controllers to other view controllers.

Comment: its normal to add a view controller on top of another one, its not normal to modify your apps delegate root view controller though.

Comment: So I should be using a separate UIViewController as the rootViewController then add Controller 1 and 2 to that stack as needed?

Comment: yes, and if you prefer you can make that viewcontroller handle the presenting and dismissing. (by the way you should be using the interface builder too)

Comment: I'm using IB for some things but not many. Also I don't know storyboards yet. I will accept your answer if you want to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following two methods to present and dismiss view controllers.

Present:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

Dismiss:

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

You just have to set the animated property to YES on the dismiss and to NO on the present to achieve what you want to do. You can also use the completion block to chain view controllers.